# Removing the values from a smaller dataframe from a larger dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe in pandas where one of the columns is labeled "Col2" and the row values for this column contain a long string. I parsed out of this dataframe another smaller dataframe that has column "Col2" values that I'd like to remove from the original. Basically, I'd like to iterate through the original dataframe and remove whole rows based upon having Col2 values that match the subset dataframe; Essentally subtracting one dataframe from another based upon Col2 values. How can I do this?

Comment: It would be good to post the code you tried and some sample data, masked if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted

```
from pandas import DataFrame

d2 = DataFrame([[5,6],[7,8],[3,4]],columns=["a","b"])

   a  b
0  5  6
1  7  8
2  3  4

d1=DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=["a","b"])

   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4


ind = d2.a.isin(d1.a).tolist()
ind=map(lambda x : x[0],filter(lambda x : x[1]==True,list(enumerate(ind))))

d2.drop(ind)
   a  b
0  5  6
1  7  8
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.
let me know your views.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],'col2':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O']})
df2= pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,5,11],'col2':['A','D','K']})

#for each value in col2 of df2 search whole of df1 col2
for x in df2['col2']:
    for y in df.iterrows():

        #if they are equal then drop the row from df and reasign it to df
        if y[1]['col2'] == x:
            df=df.drop(y[0])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.query(-df1.Col2.isin(df2.Col2))
```

Here is the output of my code:

```
import pandas as pd  

df1 =pd.DataFrame({'X' :  pd.Series(['xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'hh']),
                       'Y' :  pd.Series(['ghj', 'dbj', 'lmf', 'hhjk']),
                       'Col2' :  pd.Series(['abd', 'def','ghi','jkl'])
                      })

 Col2   X    Y
0  abd  xx  ghj
1  def  yy  dbj
2  ghi  zz  lmf
3  jkl  hh  hjk

df2 =pd.DataFrame({'X' :  pd.Series(['www', 'ddd' ]),
                   'Col2' :  pd.Series([ 'def', 'jkl'])
                  })


  Col2    X
0  def  www
1  jkl  ddd

df1.query(-df1.Col2.isin(df2.Col2))

  Col2   X    Y
0  abd  xx  ghj
2  ghi  zz  lmf
```